Threlte stopPropagation on click event
Using Threlte i can create two shapes in a file like so :
<T.Mesh on:click={(e) => console.log("little shape") } >
</T.Mesh>

<T.Mesh on:click={(e) => console.log("bigger shape") } >
</T.Mesh>

In order to avoid the second shape to tigger it's event on a click on the small one, I can add e.stopPropagation() like so :
<T.Mesh on:click={(e) => {console.log("little shape"); e.stopPropagation() }}>
</T.Mesh>

Issue comes when I wants to create a separate component out of my little shape. stopping propagation inside the other file is pointless, and stopImmediatePropagation() isn't recognized as a function.
App.svelte
<LittleShape
  on:click >
>/LittleShape>

<T.Mesh
   on:click={(e) => {console.log("bigger shape") }} >
</T.Mesh>

LittleShape.svelte
<T.Mesh></T.Mesh>

How can I split my file while preventing propagation
Thanks in advance!

Why do you think "stopping propagation inside the other file is pointless"?

For an event propagation control (in a separate component) it's needed to ensure that the event is properly stopped within the child component AND that this behavior is correctly communicated to the parent.
One way to go is to handle the click event within the LittleShape component and prevent the event from propagating up the DOM tree (even when it’s in a separate file). Untested example App.svelte:
<script>
  import LittleShape from './LittleShape.svelte';
</script>

<LittleShape />

<T.Mesh on:click={(e) => {console.log("bigger shape")}}>
</T.Mesh>

And LittleShape.svelte:
<script>
  function handleClick(event) { 
    console.log("little shape");
    event.stopPropagation(); // event.stopPropagation() is called, so when LittleShape is clicked, the event won’t propagate to the parent (preventing the bigger shape click handler from being triggered)
  }
</script>

<T.Mesh on:click={handleClick}></T.Mesh>

